# ASP NET Core Use Async Mediator with DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await, dbcontext, mediator

I am trying to access the dbContext via Dependency Injection. And it works.

I am adding the dbcontext in startup

```
Services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseMySql(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"],
                    b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Persistence"));
                options.UseOpenIddict();
            });
```

I am Also adding all the request Handlers in Mediator

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(ChangePasswordRequestHandler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

I am calling a request inside in another request in the mediator. Here is a sample

```
    public class CreateComment : IRequestHandler<CreateCommentRequestModel, ResponseViewModel>
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;
        public CreateComment(ApplicationDbContext context, IMediator mediator)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mediator = mediator;
        }

        public async Task<ResponseViewModel> Handle(CreateCommentRequestModel request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _ = _mediator.Send(new SendCommentNotificationRequestModel(), CancellationToken.None);
            return new ResponseViewModel();
        }
```

Here is another request Handler

```
    public class SendCommentNotification : IRequestHandler<SendCommentNotificationRequestModel, ResponseViewModel>
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;
        public SendCommentNotification(ApplicationDbContext context, IMediator mediator)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mediator = mediator;
        }

        public async Task<ResponseViewModel> Handle(SendCommentNotificationRequestModel request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await _mediator.Send(new SendNotificationToManyRequestModel(), CancellationToken.None);
            return new ResponseViewModel();
        }
    }
```

Here is my Third Handler

```
    public class SendNotificationToMany : IRequestHandler<SendNotificationToManyRequestModel, ResponseViewModel>
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly INotificationService _notificationService;
        public SendNotificationToMany(
            INotificationService notificationService, ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _notificationService = notificationService;
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<ResponseViewModel> Handle(SendNotificationToManyRequestModel request,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
           //DbContext is disposed hence not usable when accessed here.

            return new ResponseViewModel();
        }
    }
```

The issue is that the DbContext is disposed when working on the third Handler. What can I do to resolve this?

If I add `await` on the first handler then it works as it should but I don't want to wait for it I want this to run in background.

I know the fix is very small but I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: _but I don't want to wait for it_ - you need to wait for it. Why you don't want to?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the error is located here:

```
public async Task<ResponseViewModel> Handle(CreateCommentRequestModel request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _ = _mediator.Send(new SendCommentNotificationRequestModel(), CancellationToken.None);
    return new ResponseViewModel();
}
```

You are missing the `await` keyword, although you are calling an async method.

So add it in `_ = await _mediator.Send(new SendCommentNotificationRequestModel(), CancellationToken.None);` and you should be golden.

Answer (score 0):

Kestrel creates a service scope for the lifetime of the request. When the scope is finished, all `IDisposable` services are disposed.

You will either need to keep the request lifetime open, perhaps by finding a way to await your task *after* the response has been written to the client.

Or post your background job to a background service, which would open a new scope for each request.